# How to solve optimal control problem for 2D planar spacecraft launch problem?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, lagrange-multiplier, optimal-control

$m$ is mass of spacecraft, F is trust force, $\varphi$ is angle between trust vector and horizontal plane, $\gamma$ is gravitational acceleration

Given state variables as:
$$
\begin{align}
x_1&=x & x_2&=y &
x_3&=\dot{x} & x_4&=\dot{y} &
u_1&=\frac{F}{m} & u_2&=\varphi
\end{align}
$$

SC starts from $(0,0)$ at $t=0$ and reaches to altitude $H$ with horizontal velocity $V$ at that altitude.

***I have 3 questions to solve:***

**a)**
Solve the lagrange multipliers and write down the following expressions by obtaining $\tan(u_2)$ as a function of $t$ and $\dot{x}$ vector wrt $u_1$ & $u_2$

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial x_1^*}{\partial u_2^*}&=\frac{x_3^*}{K cos^2(u_2^*)} & \frac{\partial x_2^*}{\partial u_2^*}&=\frac{x_4^*}{K cos^2(u_2^*)}\\
\frac{\partial x_3^*}{\partial u_2^*}&=\frac{u_1^*}{K cos(u_2)} & \frac{\partial x_4^*}{\partial u_2^*}&=\frac{u_1^* sin(u_2^*)-\gamma}{K cos^2(u_2^*)}
\end{align}
$$
where $K=\frac{d Tanu_2}{d t}=Constant$

***My Solution is:***

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}\tan (u_2^*)=K
\quad
\Rightarrow
\quad
\tan (u_2^*)=Kt
\quad
\Rightarrow
\quad
t=\frac{\tan (u_2^*)}{K}
\end{align}4$$

$$
\begin{align}
x_1=\int \dot{x_1} dt=x_3 t
\quad
\Rightarrow
\quad
x_1=\frac{x_3}{K} \tan (u_2^*)
\quad
\Rightarrow
\quad
\frac{\partial x_1^*}{\partial u_2^*}=\frac{x_3^*}{K \cos^2(u_2^*)}
\end{align}
$$

and so on... ***Is that correct?***

**b)** Solve the differential equations(which were found before as initial conditions, cost function, hamiltonian, lagrange multipliers) if $u_1=\frac{F}{m}=U=constant$ and $u_2(0)$ and $u_2(t_f)$ are free;

I don't know what to do if control is free to choose at initially and finally.

I know one boundary condition [image]

where if state $x(t_f)$ is free its variation $\delta x_f$ cannot be $0$. Thus, corresponding lagrange multiplier $p^*$ should be $0$

**But I don't know what *"control is free"* means.**

Comment: "Free" here means "unspecified and to be determined as part of solving the problem."

Comment: Ok but how it route me to solve the problem? I don't know what to do with the information and solve the equation wrt that. :/

Comment: To help you, one would have to know which variables are the control variables.  What do the asterisks mean?  Costates?  Don't assume the notation in your course is universal.

Comment: Ok. Sorry. asteriks means optimal solution just ignore it. Costates are lagrange multipliers  notated as p here. Control variablese are u_1 and u_2.

Comment: Also, what are the state equations for the variables $u_{1}, u_{2}$?  Please edit your question to specify the control model completely.  (I don't have any more time to work on your question, but you'll have a better chance with the other answerers.)

Comment: I have the information required at the first line of my question. u1 is trust force and u2 is steering angle.

Comment: Are $u_{1}, u_{2}$ the control variables, then?  Because you listed them under state variables.  Anyway, good luck with other answerers.

Comment: Ok yes you are right. I just coppied them from the pdf but I think those are obvious.